# On which SE site should I ask language independent programming questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which SE site is the place to ask questions like "How do I avoid global variables?" .
These questions are asking for different approaches to a problem which are not language specific and may be applied to all languages, The code used to describe the problem is usually pseudo code, and the problem looks "Too broad" or vague but it isn't actually.
Here are some examples:
How do I avoid global variables?
How do I change the program flow within an infinite loop without breaking it? (with pseudo code, current and expected program flow provided)

Comment: Certainly there are questions which are language-independent, mostly about algorithm design and performance. But the two examples you give are not language independent: the methods one employs to avoid global variables in, say, my favorite language, J, are very different from the patterns you'd use in, say, C. Or Haskell. Or JS. Similarity for flow control: to the extent possible, that's actually avoided in J, so the second question isn't even applicable to that particular language.